# Hide or Change the Centos Information at login

Tags: centos, login

How could we turn off the information text in the centos login screen?

[image]

Comment: for security reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify `/etc/issue` (and, if it exists, `/etc/issue.net`).

Comment: The `motd` is displayed after login; `issue` is displayed before.  Forgive me for adding this, but if you're happy with this answer, don't forget to accept it by clicking the tick outline.  My apologies if you're already familiar with the etiquette.